# Writing I/O wrappers for arbitrary application (linux)

Tags: linux, user-interface, wrapper

How can I write a wrapper that executes an arbitrary application and controls it's I/O to filter user input or add it's own input? Output control would be nice too. This is in Linux and preferably using a scripting language such as BASH or Python but C++ or Java will work for me too.

For my specific application I have downloaded Mupen64Plus (a Nintendo 64 emulator) and the latest version does not come with a GUI of any kind, besides a window showing the emulated display. I can use it well enough but it would be convenient to make a GUI for it to pass file selections, save/load state commands, and other such commands to it. It would also be nice to be capable of adding features that don't exist in the emulator such as video/sound capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into XTest. [Here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xtest-0.2/docs/Graphics-X11-XTest.html) is a Haskell API for it (I know, Haskell, random!)

Or you might prefer `java.awt.Robot`.

Comment: So those work by momentarily hijacking the user's mouse and keyboard? That could work but the application must have focus, which it wont. Of course, I could switch focus, send the commands, and switch back in milliseconds but it is no cleaner than using screen nor does it offer any more (or less) of my desired features.

Comment: I guess there aren't any other solutions to this problem so I'd say it's time to accept one. As far as solving my problem is concerned this answer is equivalent to mine but I think it is more useful for the generalized form of my question so I'll accept this one. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Wait, actually it's the only solution to my specific problem. I just realized that I can't get any commands to mupen64plus just via the command line to it's stdin, not counting any arguments I can give it when I call it.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have a solution to this which I use to manage a small Minecraft server I have, but it feels dirty and a little hackish and I feel there ought to be a cleaner solution. I suppose this is mostly because it is easily possible for the user to disrupt it albeit only if they chose to.

Use screen, the BASH application as your wrapper. Write a GUI that executes `screen -dmS mupen64` and forwards any commands you give it to the screen named mupen64 and (if desired) read stdout from the screen.

This technique has several flaws however. It only allows access to stdin, stdout, and stderr with no access to keyboard or mouse input nor it's video or sound output.

Comment: It may be possible to augment these weaknesses by writing to tty but I don't know anything about that. It is still not a complete solution even then however.